# How can I parse string into Hiccup?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, om, reagent, hiccup

How can I parse a string of Hiccup into a Hiccup node?

For example, 
`"[:b 'hello world']"` into `[:b "hello world"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use reader to convert string to data structures:

```
user=> (clojure.edn/read-string "[:b 'hello world']")
[:b 'hello world']
```

You should use `"` to denote string:

```
user=> (clojure.edn/read-string "[:b \"hello world\"]")
[:b "hello world"]
```

Comment: Thanks! For those using Clojurescript you'll want `[cljs.reader]`